# Alternatives to repository access from domain (DDD)

Tags: domain-driven-design

I've seen a number of these questions, but they always seem to mismatch my thoughts.
I think it is due to my sloppy understanding of the relationship between aggregates-aggregate roots-entities-value objects.

The finished solutions just looks like DTOs to me, since everything (all logic) seems to end up inside repositories. Perhaps I've been looking at EF tutorials too much.

Assuming we have an extremely simple class, with a first version of a repo (let's ignore that it only handles a single person):

```
class Person 
{
    int Age;
    void MakeOlder() { Age++; }
}
interface IPersonRepository
{
    Person GetAPerson();
}
```

Now, what I would like to do from an UI (say, at the press of a button), is **not**:

```
person.MakeOlder();
_repo.Save(person);
```

But perhaps just:

```
person.MakeOlder();
```

For me, the action of "MakeOlder" is what should trigger a save. But of course this would require a reference to repo in Person.
The only options to this, that I can think of, is:

```
_repo.MakePersonOlder(person);
```

(Seems awful.)

```
person.MakeOlder(_repo);
```

(No gain from the UI pov, which is what I'm looking at now)

```
class Person : IMyEntityBaseType { ...
    void MakeOlder() { 
        Age++; 
        EntityDataWasChangedNowIWantToBeSaved(); 
    }
}
```

Or some variant of this; events, AOP, etc. Somehow signalling or capturing that a save should be done.

I think I also might be mixing my view of DDD up with Event sourcing and similar concepts.

Am I completely wrong in thinking that a `SavePerson` call in UI code feels dirty?

What is the "right" thing to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't pass repository to Person. With that model, you'd have to pass the repository to every method. Typically, if using EF or some other ORM, there is a built-in concept of a [unit of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). A unit of work keeps track of all objects that have changed within a defined interaction. When you commit a unit of work, it commits all the changes within it. The code would look more like:

```
person.MakeOlder();
_unitOfWork.Commit();
```

This approach can be used when there are changes to multiple entities. Since the ORM keeps track of the changes, you don't have to explicitly save each object which is part of the unit of work.

A better option, which also addresses you concern, is to encapsulate the use case with an [application service](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/). The application service would have a method such as:

```
public void MakeOlder(int personId)
{
   var person = this.personRepository.Get(personId);
   person.MakeOlder();
   this.unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

The UI would then call the application service instead of the domain object directly.

Comment: eulerfx was faster than me. I'll add just that the reason for which the Person doesn't need to to use the repository is Separation of Concerns. Person is a domain object, it models Domain and it doesn't care a bit about persistence or where is actually used or by whom. It's simply not its responsibility.

Comment: Ok, fine, but I still feel that the examples are lacking some actual code to get the full context.

I then assume that the UI still will see the domain objects, and that we separate the "commands" from queries, aka cqrs?

Or should UI code call ApplicationService.GetPerson() ("onion architecture"?)?

Comment: You can have the app service return domain objects to the UI or read-only objects, making it more like CQRS. I prefer the latter approach since it keeps the domain fully encapsulated by the app service.

Answer (score 0):

Could'nt agree more. You were missing the ApplicationService concept. Application Layer is way important.

I just dont agree with you on :

> The finished solutions just looks like DTOs to me, since everything (all logic) seems to end up >inside repositories.

This is because you need to understand the Layers better. The presentation layer (UI) will call na ApplicationService (Façade). The MakePersonOlder(int personId) as suggested.

The Application layer is responsible for coordination of actions :)

One of these actions might be save to repositories, log to a text file, send e-mails, and so on.

Gotcha?

Bruno